# Misspelled middle name in passport

Tags: tickets, passports

My middle name on my passport is missing one letter, so different from my ticket.  Will this be an issue? Doroty vs Dorothy

Comment: You should be able to get your passport reissued for free if the mistake was made by the passport office.

Comment: Is the passport or the ticket right?

Comment: @JoErNanO The ticket is right, according to "on my passport is missing one letter".

Comment: There is a good answer at the question [Middle name missing on flight reservation, API needs middle name](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36522/middle-name-missing-on-flight-reservation-api-needs-middle-name?rq=1)

Comment: This should be fixed and the link changed to @VolkerSiegel's -- the linked answer is *last name* but this question is about *middle name*.

Comment: @chx I agree it needs to be changed. The currently linked answer is actually wrong for this question. I flagged this question asking to change it; The following is the message for the flag: It is a duplicate, but of a different answered question. The referenced answer [My last name is not the same on ticket as on passport; rest of details are same] is actually wrong for this question. There is a real duplicate, which has an answer that is correct for this question. Also, that answer is very interesting and well sourced. Please change the duplicate reference, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely not a problem but at least in one case [Passenger refused flight over missing letter on airline ticket](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/edmonton/passenger-refused-flight-over-missing-letter-on-airline-ticket-1.2891783) -- but the title is sensational if you read carefully all the airline said they can't guarantee the connecting airline won't have a problem.

This [thread](http://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k6217944-Wrong_spelling_of_middle_name-Air_Travel.html) reports a number of cases when this hasn't been a problem.

This [forum post](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/7386078-post3.html) says

> Turns out I've been flying with different middle names on my [driving licence] and passport for years. Tickets match passport, but I've often showed my DL and no one has batted an eye.

Summary: I would call the airline especially if you are connecting.

Comment: Hmmm... I do not know what a DL is - but independant of that, I would expect that it's only relevant that the passport and the ticket match, nothing else - simply because only these two should be required at the airport - or am I missing something?

Comment: DL is driving license. Often it is good enough if it's not international flight.