# E-Ticket in Chinese Language

Tags: tickets, jetstar

I am travelling from Kuala Lumpur to Singapore on a Jetstar flight. I booked this ticket through a travel agency (trip.com). While booking the ticket I forgot to mention my middle name so I had to contact the Jetstar customer to add the middle name in the ticket. However, after adding the middle name, the itinerary that I received is in the Chinese language. When I asked Trip.com for the itinerary in English, they told me that they have received only the Chinese version from the airline. Also, when I go to the airline's website, I can only see my first name and last name in the manage booking section.

Is it okay to carry the Chinese version of booking confirmation to the airport?

Comment: Do you have the reservation number or (PNR)? if so, then retrieve it and print it on [jetstar website](https://booknow.jetstar.com/RetrieveBooking.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I do have that, but it still doesn't show my middle name in the ticket.

Comment: retrieve a copy from https://booknow.jetstar.com/RetrieveBooking.aspx

Comment: Middle names are usually optional on flight bookings, as far as I know. Your API will include it however, if you need to provide API for this flight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Middle name missing on flight reservation, API needs middle name](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36522/middle-name-missing-on-flight-reservation-api-needs-middle-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days you can check in online for almost all airlines.
When you do that, make sure you get your boarding pass in a language you can understand or if impossible, make an (online) translation to use besides it.

If you do not check in before going to the airport, print your Chinese form and add, if possible, an online translation for yourself to understand.

Do not worry about a missing name, middle names are very often not printed on boarding passes (and when they are, they are often shortened anyhow.) When you enter your passport details, as you will be asked to do before the travel for the API information, you will enter your middle name when asked.
Not all countries insist on middle names, and when they do they sometimes ask for middle name initials. If so, you do not have to worry about the full name.